# Rabbit MQ publish confirm questions

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, amqp

i just have a question about publish confirm
as far as i know if i want to make sure that the message is delivered successfully i should wait for ack synchronously or asynchronously
the most recommended way to use publish confirm is wait for confirmation async to maximize the throughput and the reason mentioned is at constant load rabbit confirm messages to the disk every few milliseconds so if i wait synchronously the latency could be few hundred of milliseconds as well
so my question is if i wait for the acks asynchronously  will the message be available for consumers before the message written to the disk and before the ack delivered to the publisher and if yes? how this will grantee that the message will be delivered once if the consumer will have access to the message before it written to the disk.

Comment: You can use another queue for messages which are delivered .And if the message is processed in the destination service you can publish a message to this queue.

Comment: As a another solution you can use kafka because it is more faster that Rabbit, and you can use group consumers for reading the messages faster

Comment: thanks Ehsan for your answer. But i am trying to understand how this model work. As they said in their documentation that publish confirm Async will make things faster. but i dont know how this will happen

Comment: Do you get the ack signal in your application for published messages?

Comment: btw my problem is not in consuming my problem is to understand when the message will be ready for consuming after publishing .will it be after i receive the ack at publisher or before.